# SharePoint Workflow with replicatorActivity and onWorkflowItemChanged

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

Has anyone had success with adding an onWorkflowItemChanged Activity inside a replicatorActivity? It seems to only fire when outside the Replicator.

Scenario is the following:

Several users are assigned a task inside the replicator. If the Workflow Item is modified then we want to cancel all the tasks and assign new ones based on the change that was made. Problem is that onWorkflowItemChanged doesn't get fired when placed inside the replicatorActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Yess, [there is a solution (a workaround?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279813/ontaskchanged-event-being-fired-within-listenactivity-but-not-onworkflowitemchan)!