# OnTaskChanged event being fired within ListenActivity, but not OnWorkflowItemChanged

Tags: sharepoint, events, workflow

I'm monitoring for either

- Workflow Task Change
- Workflow Item Change

OnApprovalTaskChanged is being fired, but not onWorkflowItemChanged. Is this a known issue and what could be a workaround?

If i remove ListenActivity, onWorkflowItemChanged gets triggered!

Here is part of my workflow:
[Workflow diagram http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/8397/ss20100217113727.png](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/8397/ss20100217113727.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue. [This article helped me](http://blogs.msdn.com/yvan_duhamel/archive/2009/11/25/workflow-locks-because-of-onworkflowitemchanged-event-handler.aspx).

What you must do is to set InitializeWorkflow activity and create new correlation token for that activity. Parent for this correlation token must be set parent sequence activity. Then use this new token on OnWorkflowItemChanged event.

Everything for me works as expected if activities put in following order:

```
-Replicator (i have to create multiple tasks)
--Sequence
--some stuff 
---InitializeWorkflow (this activity is for bugfix, create new token, parent=Sequence)
---While (in my case: while task changed or wf item changed)
----ListenActivity
-----EventDriven (OnTaskChanged)
-----EventDriven (OnWorkflowItemChanged, use newly created token)
```

Putting another sequence and initializeworkflow in WHILE loop resulted in OnWorkflowItemChanged being called only first time item changes.

Comment: looks promising, let me try this

Comment: Unexpected System.InvalidOperationException: This operation can not be performed at runtime.     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dependencyProperty, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean shouldCallSetValueOverrideIfExists)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dependencyProperty, Object value)     at System.Workflow.Activities.CallExternalMethodActivity.set_CorrelationToken(CorrelationToken value),  I got this error when manually setting the token, how did you do?

Comment: @Wint I cannot find particular code I did use this thing or maybe I did it in a different way...

Are you sure you did it as indicated by the linked [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/yvan_duhamel/archive/2009/11/25/workflow-locks-because-of-onworkflowitemchanged-event-handler.aspx)? Looks like you are assigning correlation token on runtime, try to make it with the designer and bind to CorrelationToken property for InitializeWorkflow action. (Don't forget to point OwnerActivityName to parent sequence activity). Then bind that CorrelationToken with designer for onWorkflowItemChanged event.